# OpenSSH: if the server is set to "PasswordAuthentication no" then is there any risk if the *client* is set to "PasswordAuthentication yes"?

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

For all my servers `PasswordAuthentication` is set to `no` in the `sshd_config` file. This means that only key authentication is allowed.

In this situation, is there any risk if `PasswordAuthentication` is set to `yes` in the **client's** `ssh_config`?

Comment: Could you possibly explain what you mean by "risk" and whether your concern is regarding some risk on the server or on the client side of things?

Comment: Hi kusalananda. What I had in mind was a (theoretical or not) risk to the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a risk, if the client connects to the wrong machine, and that machine allows password auth.  Then the user may enter their password, thinking it might be a server side change... and now the password can be stolen.

Related: [Is your SSH password revealed when you attempt to connect to the wrong server?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309938/is-your-ssh-password-revealed-when-you-attempt-to-connect-to-the-wrong-server/309940#309940)

Comment: Thanks. A theoretical but real risk. This is the correct answer.